# Maybe switchIfEmpty lazy evaluation

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I use `Maybe` `switchIfEmpty` method to provide an alternate result if the source `Maybe` is empty. However, I would like the alternate source to be executed only when the source is empty and not execute it when the source is not empty.

In the following example I would like to avoid execution of `costlyFallback` if the source returned non-empty `Maybe`. The current implementation always calls it because it is required to be passed to `switchIfEmpty` method. `Maybe.fromCallable` looks promising, however it will work only with callables which exludes returning a `Maybe.empty`. Any hints are appreciated. Would be nice if `switchIfEmpty` would accept some lazily evaluated `Maybe` provider.

```
public class StartRxMaybe {

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(new StartRxMaybe().start().blockingGet());
}

private Maybe<Integer> start() {
    return func()
        .switchIfEmpty(costlyFallback());
}

private Maybe<Integer> func() {
    System.out.println("Non-empty maybe returned");
    return Maybe.just(1);

}

private Maybe<Integer> costlyFallback() {
    System.out.println("Fallback executed anyway");
    return LocalDate.now().getMonth() == Month.JULY
        ? Maybe.just(2)
        : Maybe.empty();
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Using [`Maybe.defer`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5358) does the trick and allows to pass the supplier:

```
private Maybe<Integer> start() {
    return func()
        .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.defer(this::costlyFallback));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **@nosalan**, here is my solution for Kotlin:

```
fun getOperator(id: Int): Single<Operator> {
    return db.getOperator(id)
        .switchIfEmpty(Single.defer { api.getOperators }
                .flattenAsFlowable { it }
                // etc.
        )
}
```

Note `{}` instead of `()` in `defer`.